# Extracting text between delimiters - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, delimiter, text-extraction

this is my first post. I have a text (.txt) file that contains journal entries from multiple sources. I'm looking to organize the entries by date, author, title, etc.
Each entry is separated by "---".
Each date is given after the "|".
Each author is in parentheses.
The Title comes before the parentheses at the top of the entry.

So a typical entry looks like:

```
Title (Author) - Citation | Date Added

Entry
---
```

Here is my code so far:

```
$text = file_get_contents('./uploads/My Clippings.txt');

$entries = explode("==========",$text);

$count = count($entries);
echo "<h3>You have $count entries on your Kindle!</h3><br />";

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo $entry . "<br /><br />";
}
```

So now I have an array of entries separate by the "---" delimiter.
Next I want to split each string in the array by the author, title, etc...

The problem is that preg functions are only applicable to arrays and this won't work if each array element is a string.

I know there are several ways to approach this problem I just can't seem to find one that works in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "preg functions are only applicable to arrays". `preg_*` functions work on strings, and i think you need `preg_match_all`. But maybe I've missed the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this?

```
<?php
    $string = 'Dune 2000 (Frank Herbert) - Some Citation | 2011-05-25';
    $pattern = '/(.*) \((.*)\) \- (.*) \| (.*)/';
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dune 2000 (Frank Herbert) - Some Citation | 2011-05-25
    [1] => Dune 2000
    [2] => Frank Herbert
    [3] => Some Citation
    [4] => 2011-05-25
)
```

Comment: If prefixed with `^` this regex would probably also be suitable to `preg_match_all` the whole input file at once.

Answer (score 0):

For each entry that is like this `Title (Author) - Citation | Date Added` you would:

- find the first occurence of `_(` where underline is a space, and then your title is the substring from 0 to that index
- find `(` and `)` indices, and the substring with those indices is your author
- find the indices of `-_` and of `_|` where underline is a space, and the substring with those indices is your citation
- find the index of `|_` where underline is a space, and the substring from that index to the last character would be your date